# Bumblebee build kernel module

Tags: nvidia, kernel, bumblebee

I've had nvidia-prime together with prime-indicator working when I first set it up.

A few days ago I've installed kernel 4.7; after doing this, I noticed that prime-indicator was showing the nvidia symbol, but actually using Intel graphics. Switching using nvidia-settings wasn't working either.

So, I decided to use bumblebee instead. Removed and purged nvidia* etc.
Installed bumblebee like described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee). Later, I also tried [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-install-and-configure-bumblebee.html) method.

In both cases, optirun/primusrun tell me 'Could not load GPU driver'. So, I went to Bumblebee troubleshooting, and it seems like my nvidia .ko files are not present. (bumblebeed: Module 'nvidia' is not found.)

troubleshooting: "Then ensure that you the module is built."

How does one build these kernel modules?

---

update:

I've tried using dkms autoinstall for my nvidia drivers, this was its output:

```
Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' -j8 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.7.0-040700-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/4.7.0-040700-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.7.0-040700-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.7.0-040700-generic (x86_64)
```

So, is my kernel not supported?

---

My setup: XPS15 9550 laptop, Ubuntu 16.04 on kernel 4.7.0-040700-generic.

Comment: I've tried using dkms autoinstall for my nvidia drivers, this was its output:
    Building module:
    cleaning build area....
    'make' -j8 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.7.0-040700-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/4.7.0-040700-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules.....(bad exit status: 2)
    ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.7.0-040700-generic is not supported
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.7.0-040700-generic (x86_64)

So, is my kernel not supported?

Comment: Bumblebee is depreciated, it is replace by Nvidia-prime. This is a really OTT way to fix an icon glitch. Just roll back the kernel to when it worked, from grub choose `advanced options for ubuntu` and choose the last working kernel.

Comment: In addition to rolling back kernel to last known working version, you can also try updating your 4.7.0 kernel to current version 4.7.2 which **might** fix the problem.

Comment: @MarkKirby Aside from the icon problem, the profile was not switching and I wasn't able to get it to work after troubleshooting...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it is working now.

Steps:

- Completely remove everything that has to do with nvidia, bumblebee and dependencies.
- Update to kernel 4.7.2 (Not sure if this was the key)
- Installed nvidia-367 through the additional drivers interface, rebooted.
- Added `ppa:bumblebee/testing`.
- Installed bumblebee, bumblebee-nvidia, primus and prime-indicator through synaptics.
- Ran `sudo prime-select intel` and rebooted.
- Modified `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`, replacing 'current' with '367', rebooted.

Now I can switch globally using prime-indicator or run a specific app using primusrun.